# Matlab outputs numeraical numbers in multiple terms rather than in float

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab to calculate a definite integration which involves the natural constant `e` as the based.

Here is my input and output:

```
  >> syms t
  >> f=t/10^5*0.001*exp(-0.001*t);
  >> int(f,t,0,5000)

  ans =

  1/100 - (3*exp(-5))/50
```

I am wondering why I get a result with multiple terms rather than a numerical result? Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Read about Matlab's [Symbolic Math toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-symbolic-math-toolbox.html) here. Or maybe you shouldn't be using symbolic math at all, in which case look at numerical quadrature and the [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just do?

```
I = int(f,t,0,5000);
double(I)
```

Comment: thank you. So why Matlab does not directly output the exact number?

Comment: Because you are doing symbolic calculations, and so the result is a symbolic expression. If you want a numerical result, you have to convert it to the right data type.